# Problem changing the Foreground colour of a WPF DataGrid Cell using MultiBinding

Tags: wpf, datagrid, multibinding

I am trying to change the Foreground colour of a DataGridCell, NOT the entire row, given the value of the specific cell contents. For example, if the date value of the cell is out of date then I want to set the Foreground to red. I am almost where I am using MultiBinding to extract two values from the data grid and parsing it through value converter which implements IMultiValueConverter.

In short, and without then need to go into the converter itself, I have written the following XAML:

```
<GlobalTasks:CellHighlighterConverter x:Key="cellHighlighterConverter"/>

<Style x:Key="CellHighlighterStyle">
    <Setter Property="my:ExtendedDataGrid.Foreground">
        <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource cellHighlighterConverter}">
                <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource self}"/>
                    <Binding Path="Row" Mode="OneWay"/>
                </MultiBinding.Bindings>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>            
</Style>
```

I then added to  my Datagrid : `CellStyle="{StaticResource CellHighlighterStyle}"`.

Now, my converter sees the first `Value[0]` property as the DataGridCell but the second value is some sort of made up DependencyProperty. It’s like it has created a default or dummy property when I actually want to get the row. In fact, I would really like to get the class object associated to that row. My DataGrid is bound to a `List<of a class object>`.

I am sure that I am inches away. How do I parse either the DataGrid Row so that I can extract the value of the field, or the object bound to that row or column itself in order for me to return the colour I want to return? OR, is there a better way for me to selectively alter the properties of a DataGrid Cell given the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataContext of the cell should be the data-object of the row, try changing the second binding to this:

```
<Binding />
```

Which binds directly to the DataContext.

Comment: Absolutely spot on. Thanks for your reply. It worked perfectly.